# Jupyter notebook does not open from conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

for some reasons I am unable to open jupyter notebook from newly created conda environment.

What I am doing is next:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.9
source activate myenv
conda install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

What I am getting when trying to start jupyter notebook is this Error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/comp1/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/_device.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZdaPvSt11align_val_t
  Referenced from: /Users/comp1/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/libc++.1.dylib
Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
 in /Users/comp1/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks.